# How to get grand total without shipping costs from a Magento order model?

Tags: magento

I have a Magento order model that I create like this:

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId);
```

Now I want to get the order grand total including the taxes etc., but without the shipping costs. I can retrieve the grand total with `$order->getGrandTotal()`, but how can I exclude the shipping costs?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The subtotal doesn't include shipping, is that what you mean?

Comment: No, because the subtotal also does not include the taxes...

Answer (score 39, accepted):

```
$amount = $order->getGrandTotal() - $order->getShippingAmount();
```

Try not to over-think it. ;-)

Comment: Thank you! Since I also want to subtract the shipping tax amount, I now use `$amount = $order->getGrandTotal() - $order->getShippingAmount() - $order->getShippingTaxAmount();`...

Comment: Is there a way to get the percentage of the tax rates applied in the shipping method?

Comment: Perhaps like this, `$taxPercent = 100 * $order->getShippingTaxAmount() / $order->getShippingInclTax();`

Comment: I wanted to show Total Shipping charges on my Invoice pdf inclusive of Tax. Simon your post helped me achieve that. In Abstract.php line 320 I edited it to: `$totalShippingChargesText = "(" . Mage::helper('sales')->__('Total Shipping Charges (incl GST)') . " " . $order->formatPriceTxt($order->getShippingAmount() + $order->getShippingTaxAmount()) . ")";` thanks

Comment: I received an edit suggestion which proposed to use `getTotalExclTax()` but that wouldn't exclude the shipping amount, which was the point of the question.  To anyone else who thinks they can do better then make your own answer and get the credit for it.

Answer (score 9):

Here is another quick method to get grand total incuding taxes and without shipping fee.

if you are dealing with the cart:

```
$quote = Mage::getModel('checkout/session')->getQuote();
$cartGrossTotal = 0;
foreach ($quote->getAllItems() as $item) {
 $cartGrossTotal += $item->getPriceInclTax()*$item->getQty();
}
```

if you are dealing with an order:

```
$orderGrossTotal = 0;
foreach ($order->getAllItems() as $item) {
 $orderGrossTotal += $item->getPriceInclTax()*$item->getQty();
}
```

Comment: It is probably not that performant to loop through the cart/order items - just use the built-in stuff mentioned in clockworkgeek's answer...

Comment: I'm already iterating through the items for other reasons (displaying a list of the titles of the items just purchased on the success page) so this solution is convenient.

Answer (score 1):

I think
`base_subtotal_incl_tax` can be, so
`$order->getBaseSubtotalInclTax()`

Answer (score -1):

There is one way more easy:

```
$orderValue = $order->getSubtotal();
```

Return the subtotal from the order, without shipping method;

Try it.

Comment: No, this is not an option. See the comments of the question itself: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8114985/how-to-get-grand-total-without-shipping-costs-from-a-magento-order-model/13057849#comment9968459_8114985